# sweeping edges till they get a given elevation on an oblique plane

Tags: geometry, vector-spaces, 3d, vector-analysis, computational-geometry

> I am constructing wireframe model of 3d objects (prisms,..etc.). from a triangular mesh, I
>   have obtained boundary points and fit striaght lines in order to get polygon edges refering to  prism faces. Assume, I am having polygon edges as shown in green line segments. now I want to refine  their positions.  For example, If I take upper two planes (plane P1 and P2), then I am
>   having two horizontal edges namely AB and CD. Elevation of these edges are h1 and h2 (h1 lessthan to h2). 
>   So I want to sweep the upper edge (i.e. AB edge) till it also
>   has the same elevation as in CD (lower edge). In here, I should sweep
>   the AB edge along the steepest gradient direction but on top of the P2
>   plane to come to A’B’ position.

please refer, figure to get a clear idea.

[image]

> I want to implement this in C++ and still I am struggling to find a correct way to do it as my mathematics are so poor, so that, *please
>   someone help me by given equations to do this. then i can implement in c++* Thank you